# Bash - how to expand variable when using case switches

Tags: bash, shell

Learning bash and I was thinking whether this is possible, with case or with some function..

For example..

```
./test.sh arg1 -p help,contact -e html,php # don't know how to expand them both
```

OR is it possible to do something like this?

```
./test.sh arg1 -p help -p contact -e html -e php
or 
./test.sh arg1 -p help -e html -p contact -e php
```

I want the output to be like..

> URL is www.google.com/help.html
>
> URL is www.google.com/contact.php

code:

```
var1=$1
url="http://www.google.com/"

# maybe use a for loop here??

# Okay now if I use getopts - @Hannu

while getopts ":p:e:" o; do
case "${o}" in
        p)
        page+=("$OPTARG")
        ;;
        e)
        extension+=("$OPTARG")
        ;;
esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))

#I need a better for loop here - which can expand both variables

for val in "${extension[@]}"; # 
do

# FAIL - pass first switch arguments -p and -e to for loop

echo "URL is http://www.google.com/$page.$val
done
```

OUTPUT: # closest I can get to.. first -p argument

```
./test.sh -p help -p contact -e html -e php
```

> URL is http://www.google.com/help.html
>
> URL is http://www.google.com/help.php

Comment: `$ man getopt` # one way to go

Comment: Can you check the code now? I got so close, but can expand only one with for loop

Comment: You are only iterating over `extension` array, but not over `page` array. Do you want to combine page names and extensions one to one or one to all? If first - you need `for (())` loop with index variable to iterate over both arrays. If second - you need two nested loops

Comment: I want to combine one to one (first -p with first -e). So that would be help.html and help.php, then contact.html and contact.php.  Can you show how for (()) is done for my script? I'm looking at some examples for "for loops with index variable", will update the post if I make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

okay the following seems to work. Thanks to @tso

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067504/bash-iterate-multiple-variable-with-for-loop-index

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
url="http://www.google.com/"

# maybe use a for loop here??

# Okay now if I use getopts - @Hannu

while getopts ":p:e:" o; do
case "${o}" in
        p)
        page+=("$OPTARG")
        ;;
        e)
        extension+=("$OPTARG")
        ;;
esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))


for ((i=0;i<${#extension[@]};++i));
do
echo "URL is www.google.com/${page[i]}.${extension[i]}"
done
```

Comment: About now you should be able to set this as the answer to your own question, and by that gain some status... :-)